# Synchronized deletion in TListView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a listview with lots of items.
I would like to delete some items synchronized.
Is that possible?
I have about a 100 threads that access the ListView at the same time to delete items of it.

for example:

```
 procedure Thread1 ; stdcall;
 var
  item : TlistItem;
 begin
  //...
  item.delete;
  //...
 end;

 procedure Thread2 ; stdcall;
 var
  item : TlistItem;
 begin
  //...
  item.delete;
  //...
 end;

 /.... and so on
```

The threads get fired at the same time (maybe 1ms difference between them).
Then I get lots of errors and AccessViolations.
Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: You can't access VCL visual controls from threads other than the application's main thread. The IDE even inserts a comment to tell you that when you use `File|New|Other|Thread Object` automatically. This explains the errors and access violations. (BTW, when you type `error` or `access violation`, the **very next thing** you should type is the exact error message or access violation message, including any memory addresses. Saying `errors and Access Violations` without the other information is meaningless. We can't see your screen from here. :-)

Comment: OK, Benjamin. I'll delete my second comment, and just downvote your question instead of giving you a chance to edit it to improve it. Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: Can you please explain one more time why you downvote the question?

Comment: I downvoted because you posted code that doesn't even come close to any real code you're using. You're not demonstrating what's causing the errors (or even giving the error messages you're receiving). You could have just posted `procedure DoNothing1; begin end; procedure DoNothing2; begin end;`, and it would have been the same. I asked you to improve it and provide more details so we could help, and you posted a somewhat rude comment in response. This question as written isn't useful to future readers, because it contains incomplete information that doesn't even describe the problem fully.

Comment: I asked for a synchronized solution/alternative. Not how to solve/analyze my errors. opc0de gave me a helpful link that was even the correct answer. He posted not even a little bit of code and it turns out that his "answer" is the accepted answer. I think this question should be deleted since it's not useful for you at all.

Comment: The answer you accepted does not answer the question you asked (as I mentioned in a comment to that answer). This is not a discussion site, and there is no necessity for me to discuss my reasons for downvoting your question. I explained because you asked. The usefulness of questions and answers for future readers is the **entire reason** SO exists. You might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you're not familiar with how it works here. I have nothing further to say here, Benjamin. Good luck to you in getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss Just so I understand, you have a list view with hundreds of items. Each item has a thread. You would like to make sure that both the item and the thread get deleted (destroyed) at the same time. You need to know how to perform both deletions in sync with each other, right? What I need to know is do you want to delete the thread when the item is deleted from the list, or delete the item from the list from within the thread? Or, do you want a global solution which deletes both at the same time?

Comment: Perhaps using the VirtualTreeview component can be of use since it seperates the data from the control but you as other people mentioned you should review your design: 100 threads is a lot!

Comment: Or a `TListView` in virtual mode.

Comment: -1 for the poor question and the fact that you accepted a bogus answer which I also downvoted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan much fus about nothing. Just gave an answer to an unclear question no reason to downvote I would deleted myself If i really understood the question.

Comment: @opc0de The reason to downvote is that the answer is factually incorrect

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you didn't even posted an answer...

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss The fact that I did not post an answer does not make all answers posted by other people correct

Comment: but that doesn't mean that you HAVE TO downvote answers either. Just go to the next question and see if you can help there instead of ruining others rep.

Comment: @Benjamin, I've never voted down (and met someone who downvoted my posts because of *revenge* like he thought some time ago) but in this case nothing happened with opc0de's reputation since he deleted his answer he gives the reputation back, moreover he receives the [`Peer Presure`](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge ;-)

Comment: @Benjamin, you need to review how StackOverflow works. You're **supposed** to downvote wrong answers, and upvote helpful answers. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn how it works here. If you don't agree with the way it's designed, you don't have to look for help here - the rules here are clear, and the site is designed to work a specific way. (If you get downvoted, you can always delete your question or answer, or improve it to make it better or more correct.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd create a data structure that the main application thread and all the update threads have access to, and that can be synchronised, and that ONLY the main app thread uses to update the VCL control, if this is the way you need to go.